# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php, php-8

Login form working fine, but when I enter the wrong username getting an error this

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

I have a login form with this code:

```
<?php
include('class.password.php');

class User extends Password{

    private $db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {

            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT MemberID, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = :username');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }


    public function login($username,$password){

        $user = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$user['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $user['memberID'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

}


?>
```

This is what's on the line that gives the error:

```
if($this->password_verify($password,$user['password']) == 1){
```

Comment: It's possible that `$stmt->fetch` can return false if a row isn't found.

Comment: Side note: it's a bad practice to have functions that sometimes return a value, but sometimes don't. Ensure you're either always returning a value or not returning a value at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that `get_user_hash` method will return `false` when there is no such user with provided username.
You should consider to change your code to:

```
if(!empty($user) && $this->password_verify($password,$user['password']) == 1){
```

Comment: `$this->password_verify` should be just `password_verify`.

Comment: @El_Vanja, Exactly this part of code is copied from the question. And the author told that this code works when user exists. I guess this method is inherited from `Password` class. Is it good or bad - it's another question. But I've tried to solve the question asked, not anything else

Comment: True, I missed the part that the class extends another one.

Comment: `!empty($user)` is redundant. You can just say `if($user && $this->password_verify)`